# Vuforia SDK Android Studio VS Vuforia Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

can someone say the difference beetween developing an app with the vuforia sdk in eclipse or android studio vs developing in unity with the vuforia extension?

In terms of performance, app size, and etc...

**Edit:** I'm doing an app in Unity3D, that uses a lot of 3d resources an high resolution images, but the size of my app is growing a lot, that's why I want to know if there's a notable difference between developing in android studio or Unity3D, so I can migrate my project to Android studio.

NOTE: All my content needs to be packed inside the app, I cannot use a server to send the resources, because the app needs to work in an environment with no internet connection.

Comment: What do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

late but, may help you

Yes there are multiple SDKs for Vuforia  like androidSDK and UnitySDK

Since Unity is a CrossPlatform Development Game Engine, We can Generate android project after completing project in Unity.

**Advantages of UnitySDK over androidSDK**

Since Unity is GameEngine, we can create rich 3D Environments with better UI.
Easy handling of large graphics

**Advantages of androidSDK over UnitySDK**

Since you are creating a android app with AR, with android SDK you can create app which is compatible to all the screens , we can apply lots of apis directly into vuforia player

**Disadvantages of Both**

**Unity:**
Apps created with unity created in native android , so we need to know NDK development if you want to use unity vuforia player efficiently

**Android**

not possible to handle rich 3D environments

So I Suggest you better go with Unity and then integrate it in android studio

Comment: Interms of Size, it is same for both because you are using fdx and obj files which larger in size